# SWFUploader not working in Safari and Mac Chrome

Tags: javascript, flash, safari

I'm having huge problems with this plugin. Basically, on Windows, it works fine on all 3 browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), on Mac it works fine in Firefox, but on one computer works fine in Safari too, and on the other it doesn't?!? On Mac, in Chrome it doesn't work at all.

For uploading I'm getting the -200 error (HTTP Error) and -302 as a message.

I have no idea where to go from here, this obviously is not due to programming code, it's due some weird OS-browser-flash player integration. Tried updating the Flash player to the latest version, but it doen't help. Tried clearing the cookies as well, but it's all the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't HTTP status 200 OK? (Unless you actually meant -200, and I don't know what you're referring to.)

Comment: No, that's not HTTP status, it's the SWFUpload error code, and in its source code it says that that code is assigned for HTTP Error.

Comment: I'm also fighting the same problem, but it doesn't work on Windows (Firefox) too. Would be really nice to find a solution.

Comment: Sadly, I didn't find solution to this so I decided to switch to another plugin :)